# Parse non-nested JSON array into HTML Tree View?

Tags: javascript

I am retrieving data via JSON from a database, so the data is subject to change constantly; I can't hard-code the JSON. Here is some sample JSON to illustrate this example:

```
[{"Building":"18A","Room":219,"Location":"E-4-6","BarCode":"P000019152"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"J-8-5","BarCode":"P000031111"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"J-8-5","BarCode":"P166279435"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"A-10-7","BarCode":"P352831849"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"5P04","Location":"C-4-10","BarCode":"P726526379"}, 
 {"Building":"18C","Room":"6THST","Location":"CAGE14","BarCode":"P000453262"}, 
 {"Building":"18C","Room":"6THST","Location":"CAGE13","BarCode":"P954732810"}]
```

What I need to do is parse this array and create a tree view out of it. From above, the tree view would look like this:

```
>18A
  >219
    >E-4-6
       >P000019152
>18G
  >112HALL
    >J-8-5
       >P000019152
       >P166279435
    >A-10-7
       >P166279435
  >5P04
    >C-4-10
       >P726526379
>18C
  >6THST
     >CAGE14
        >P000453262
     >CAGE13
        >P954732810
```

The important thing to note is my JSON is not structured in a way that there are parent and child objects; in other words, it is not nested. Is there any way I can parse this JSON string and create a logical and hierarchical tree view out of it, based on the order of building, room, location, then bar code?

What I've tried so far:

```
 var input=[{"Building":"18A","Room":"219","Location":"E-4-6","BarCode":"P000019152"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"J-8-5","BarCode":"P000031111"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"J-8-5","BarCode":"P166279435"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"A-10-7","BarCode":"P352831849"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"5P04","Location":"C-4-10","BarCode":"P726526379"}, 
 {"Building":"18C","Room":"6THST","Location":"CAGE14","BarCode":"P000453262"},
 {"Building":"18C","Room":"6THST","Location":"C1","BarCode":"P954732810"}];

function ToNestedObject(input){
    var i, y, len = input.length, parts, partsLen, obj = {}, prev;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        parts = input[i]; 
        partsLen = parts.length;
        prev = obj; 
        for(y = 0; y < partsLen; y++){
            prev[parts[y]] = prev[parts[y]] || {};    
            prev = prev[parts[y]];
        }
        if(!prev.ids){
            prev.ids = []; 
        }
        prev.ids.push(input[i].id); 
    }
    return obj; 
}

function ToHTML(input){
    var html = '<ul>'; 

    for(var key in input){
        if(input[key] instanceof Array){
            for(var i = 0; i < input[key].length; i++){
                html += '<li>' + input[key][i] + '</li>';
            }
        } else {
            html += '<li>' + key + ToHTML(input[key]) + '</li>';
        }           
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    return html; 
}
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ToHTML(ToNestedObject(input));
```

Comment: If you're fine with the nesting being implemented with nested `ul` elements, this is very simple to do.  What difficulty are you having doing this yourself?

Comment: Use JSON.parse to convert the string into a JS Array and then build a new Object from that Array which matches the structure you want. Finally convert that Object to HTML. I can provide a more detailed answer if you need one.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you for your response. I'm sure it is simple to some degree, but I'm pretty new to working with JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: @Snapstromegon An answer would definitely be helpful.

Comment: @MaxVoisard typically answers are provided for questions that have demonstrated an effort has been made.  So far your question has not done that.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  [ask]

Comment: @Taplar I'll edit my answer with code as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first create nested structure using recursion and the from that data create html with `ul` and `li` elements.

```js
const data = [{"Building":"18A","Room":219,"Location":"E-4-6","BarCode":"P000019152"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"J-8-5","BarCode":"P000031111"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"J-8-5","BarCode":"P166279435"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"112HALL","Location":"A-10-7","BarCode":"P352831849"}, 
 {"Building":"18G","Room":"5P04","Location":"C-4-10","BarCode":"P726526379"}, 
 {"Building":"18C","Room":"6THST","Location":"CAGE14","BarCode":"P000453262"}, 
 {"Building":"18C","Room":"6THST","Location":"CAGE13","BarCode":"P954732810"}]
const order = ['Building', 'Room', 'Location', 'BarCode'];

function nest(data, keys) {
  return data.reduce((result, e) => {
    keys.reduce((r, k, a, i) => {
      return r[e[k]] = (r[e[k]] || {})
    }, result)

    return result;
  }, {})
}

function toHtml(data, parent) {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = key;
    li.appendChild(toHtml(data[key], li))
    ul.appendChild(li)
  })
  return ul;
}

const result = nest(data, order);
const html = toHtml(result);

document.body.appendChild(html)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The front-end looks a lot better using [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/), in which you could append the child to <div id="tree"></div> by using `document.getElementById("tree").appendChild(html);` and then simply `$('#tree').jstree();`. That's what I did from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, you can use iterate through the array and hierarchy of keys to convert the array of objects into a nested hierarchy of objects. Here's a 1-liner:

```js
let values = [
  {
    "Building": "18A",
    "Room": 219,
    "Location": "E-4-6",
    "BarCode": "P000019152"
  },
  {
    "Building": "18G",
    "Room": "112HALL",
    "Location": "J-8-5",
    "BarCode": "P000031111"
  },
  {
    "Building": "18G",
    "Room": "112HALL",
    "Location": "J-8-5",
    "BarCode": "P166279435"
  },
  {
    "Building": "18G",
    "Room": "112HALL",
    "Location": "A-10-7",
    "BarCode": "P352831849"
  },
  {
    "Building": "18G",
    "Room": "5P04",
    "Location": "C-4-10",
    "BarCode": "P726526379"
  },
  {
    "Building": "18C",
    "Room": "6THST",
    "Location": "CAGE14",
    "BarCode": "P000453262"
  },
  {
    "Building": "18C",
    "Room": "6THST",
    "Location": "CAGE13",
    "BarCode": "P954732810"
  }];

let hierarchy = ['Building', 'Room', 'Location', 'BarCode'];

let output = {};
values.forEach(v => hierarchy.reduce((o, h) => o[v[h]] = o[v[h]] || {}, output));

console.log(output);
```